# TestProbe not receiving messages from RouteSpec

Tags: scala, akka, akka-testkit

I'm having issues when trying to "mock" out an Actor behind a Route. I want to be able to override and simulate functionality at test time, and I think TestProbe is the correct way to approach this.

However, I have not gotten a TestProbe to receive a single request. When using `probe.expectMsg(request)`, the test fails with `assertion failed: timeout (3 seconds) during expectMsg while waiting for GetCardRequest(12345)`. Removing the `expectMsg` and `reply` calls will still cause the test to fail due to `Request was rejected` at the `check` block. I'm expecting `val result = request ~> routes ~> runRoute` to hit the underlying TestProbe.

I feel like I'm just not understanding something simple about the setup! Thanks for the help in advance!

```scala
class MyRoutesSpec 
  extends WordSpec 
  with Matchers 
  with ScalaFutures 
  with ScalatestRouteTest
  with MyRoutes {
  lazy val routes = MyRoutes

  val probe = new TestProbe(system)
  override val cardLookupActor = probe.ref

  //TODO figure out how to get TestProbe to actually work!!
  "My Routes" should {
    "be able to get a card from a request" in {
      val cardRequest = GetCardRequest("12345")
      val cardRequestEntity = Marshal(cardRequest).to[MessageEntity].futureValue // futureValue is from ScalaFutures
      val request = Post("/getcard").withEntity(cardRequestEntity)
      val cardResponse = ClientCard("Hello", "World")

      val result = request ~> routes ~> runRoute

      probe.expectMsg(cardRequest)
      probe.reply(cardResponse)

      check {
        status should ===(StatusCodes.Created)
        contentType should ===(ContentTypes.`application/json`)
        entityAs[String] should ===("""{"cardName":"Hello", "cardType":"World"}""")
      } (result)
    }
  }
}


trait MyRoutes extends JsonSupport {

  // we leave these abstract, since they will be provided by the App
  implicit def system: ActorSystem

  lazy val log = Logging(system, classOf[MyRoutes])

  // other dependencies that Routes use
  def cardLookupActor: ActorRef

  // Required by the `ask` (?) method below
  implicit lazy val timeout = Timeout(5.seconds) 

  lazy val myRoutes: Route =
    pathPrefix("getcard") {
      concat(
        path(Segment) { id =>
          concat(
            get {
              val cardFuture: Future[ClientCard] =
                (cardLookupActor ? GetCardRequest(id = id)).mapTo[ClientCard]
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tests works but it just proves that test probe is never called.

Check this test that passes OK

```
import akka.Done
import akka.actor.ActorRef
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.event.Logging
import akka.http.scaladsl.server._
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.StatusCodes
import akka.http.scaladsl.testkit.ScalatestRouteTest
import akka.testkit.TestProbe
import akka.util.Timeout
import org.scalatest.Matchers
import org.scalatest.WordSpec
import org.scalatest.concurrent.ScalaFutures
import akka.pattern.ask

import concurrent.duration._

class MyRoutesSpec extends WordSpec with Matchers with ScalaFutures with ScalatestRouteTest with MyRoutes {

  val probe = new TestProbe(system)
  override val cardLookupActor = probe.ref

  //TODO figure out how to get TestProbe to actually work!!
  "My Routes" should {
    "be able to get a card from a request" in {
      val cardRequest = "12345"
      val request = Get("/getcard/sss").withEntity(cardRequest)
      val cardResponse = "HelloWorld"

      val result = request ~> myRoutes ~> runRoute

      probe.expectMsg(Done)
      probe.reply(cardResponse)

      check {
        status should ===(StatusCodes.OK)
        entityAs[String] should ===("""HelloWorld""")
      }(result)
    }
  }
}

trait MyRoutes {

  // we leave these abstract, since they will be provided by the App
  implicit def system: ActorSystem

  lazy val log = Logging(system, classOf[MyRoutes])

  // other dependencies that Routes use
  def cardLookupActor: ActorRef

  // Required by the `ask` (?) method below
  implicit lazy val timeout = Timeout(5.seconds)

  lazy val myRoutes: Route =
    pathPrefix("getcard") {
      path(Segment) { _ =>
        get {
          complete((cardLookupActor ? Done).mapTo[String])
        }
      }
    }
}
```

What fixed

- `lazy val routes = MyRoutes` is removed
- You send `Post` but route expects `Get`
- There is no segment passed in test, ie `/getcard` is not matched in pathPrefix("getcard") {path(Segment) {id => ???}}.
- Call `request ~> myRoutes ~> runRoute` instead of `request ~> routes ~> runRoute`
- I removed case classes just to be able to run it